# Unable to retrive dates from date column - PHP Mysql

Tags: php, date, data-retrieval

> Hi i am beginner in php, and i am try to retrieve the datas(between two dates from single column namely booking) from the table(billing_details) using the date column

below is the source code

```
$from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);
$to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']);
$from = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($from));
$to = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($to));

echo $from; 

$sql = mysql_query("select * from billing_details where SRF ='$_POST[srf]' or Service_Type ='$_POST[service]' or Status ='$_POST[status]' or Branch ='$_POST[branch]' or DATE(`Booking`) between '".$from."' and '".$to."'");

 ![I have select two different dates to get datas between the selected dates , but nothing is retrieved, only the echo $from is retrieved the the selected date][1]


Kindly help me to solve this issue, Thanks in advance

Regards,
Abdul hameed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format is incorrect and should instead be 'Y-m-d' or else mysql will not recognize it. Learn get used to that format :)

Also since you are a beginner be aware that you should check the strtotime return. Of it evaluates to false then the input is invalid and passing that to the date() function would result in 1969-12-31 i believe

Comment: Wow great i have changed the date type from $from = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($from)); to $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($from)); its working perfect, Thanks Olive Williams

Comment: You are welcome. Be sure to spend time reading both php.net/date and /strtotime to learn these functions

Comment: Oh and if this answer is the one that helped you (or another one) please click the check as the accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to assign a variable to $_POST instead of putting in like that.

**EDIT:**

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from billing_details where SRF ='$_POST[srf]' or Service_Type ='$_POST[service]' or Status ='$_POST[status]' or Branch ='$_POST[branch]' or DATE(`Booking`) between '".$from."' and '".$to."'");
```

For your $_POST[srf] and $_POST[service], put that like this:

```
$srf = $_POST['srf'];
$service = $_POST['service'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM billing_details WHERE SRF = '$srf' or Service_Type = '$service'.... etc etc")
```

Comment: I have did as like your message $_POST[from] and $_POST[to] but no improvement the same result

Comment: $from = $_POST['form'];
$to = $_POST['to'];

Comment: Undefined index: form in C:\wamp\www\Zimson\searchdata.php on line 164 the line number 164 indicates the $from = $_POST['form'];

Comment: i have changed the code as you mentioned, the issue has rectified by using the proper date syntax "instead of Y-m-d i used d-m-Y" that's why result shows empty

Comment: Ah i see. Missed that part out. Hope you got your doubts cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing single quete around your index change your query like this

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from billing_details where SRF ='".$_POST['srf']."' or Service_Type ='".$_POST['service']."' or Status ='".$_POST['status']."' or Branch ='".$_POST['branch']."' or DATE(`Booking`) between '".$from."' and '".$to."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Dont use Global directly into your query.

Learn `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql` is deprciated.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Mr.Arif, I have changed the code but the same result.

Comment: how can i share my screenshot here, so that i can show you the result page

Comment: Thanks for the support, the issue is rectified by changing the date format "instead of Y-m-d i used d-m-Y" - $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($from));